# Preserving Text Formatting with an AJAX POST request in JS

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

What I am trying to do is pass some text (commentText in the code below) to a PHP page using an AJAX request using a POST method mixed up with some flags (what=add in the code below) that tells the PHP page what this text is.

I used the post method, because it allows me to easily recover some information from the url in the PHP page:

the JS Script:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "/comment.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("what=add&comment=" + commentText);
```

the PHP file:

```
if ($_POST['what'] == "add")
{
    print_r($_POST['comment']);
    exit();
    ...
}
```

The problem I have with this approach is that because of the url-encoding, the formatting of the text (comment in the code above) is gone when I get to the PHP page. For instance if commentText is:

```
this is some comment.
And I have another line.
```

In the PHP file I get:

```
$_POST['comment'] -> "this is some comment. And I have another line."
```

The \n is gone. So by formatting to be clear, I mean essentially in this particular case, the return line (which is what I am after for now).

What would be a solution to this problem? I guess I can pass the text as plain text, but then loose the ability to use the _POST[] functionality to easily retrieve the different fields. Does that mean I somehow have to pass the data, as a plain text, and encode the fields myself within that text? Is this is the only solution or is there a better one?

Comment: what do you mean gone? gone as in empty? gone as in truncated?

Comment: What URL encoding (you aren't doing any and are depending on the browser to error correct)? What formatting? Textareas don't support any standard kind of formatting. OR did you mean white space?

Comment: @Ghost. I edited the question to precise what I mean by gone.

Comment: @Quentin@Ghost - I mean for instance \n (return line \t\r etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So while I really appreciated everyone's input, I thought, for the record, I would no so  much add my own answer, but detail a little bit some of the answers and describe what I ended up doing.

Now as Quentin suggests, but without making it really clear, is that regardless of whether the data is passed via the URL or in anything over form, eventually if this data (text) gets displayed to the browser's page, it will of course be HTML text, where in HTML, as he said, every \n, is treated as a space.

Thus regardless of what you are trying to do, if you get something like this in your text editor:

```
this is a test
on two lines
```

It will be rendered like that in the browser: `this is a test on two lines`.

Again, that's true regardless of the way you process the data (in my case passing it on to a PHP page using AJAX and the post method. Eventually the PHP page returns the content of that text to the JS script, and this text becomes HTML, thus the two lines are displayed on one line.

## SOLUTION:

I am sure they are other ways, but the one I used was indeed, as suggested, to parse the string and do the formatting of that string using HTML tags. So literarily something like this:

```
var output_text = '';
for (i = 0; i < text.length; ++i) {
    if (text.charAt(i) == '\n') {
        output_text += '<br/'>;
    }
    else if ...
}
```

Then I passed output_text to the PHP page. If it's not a problem for the PHP text to receive the an HTML encoded string then that's okay, and worse case, if you need to also store the string before the HTML encoding, then you can always pass the 2 strings to the PHP page via POST (the 'text' and 'output_text' in my example).

PS: having the question down voted wasn't necessary, and if when you do so, please explain why.

Answer (score 0):

> The \n is gone.

This has nothing to do with URL Encoding.

HTML treats, by default, any kind of whitespace as "a space".

Use a `<pre>` element, replace the new lines with `<br>` elements or pick another method to change that.

Comment: What I am saying is that instead of being on 2 lines, the text in the PHP file is on one line only. So I need to preserve the text with the line returns. I'd assume URL encoding would remove line returns as it's not a valid character for an url.

Comment: @user18490 — I know. That's what this answer covers.

Comment: Well \n is not a space? So you suggest that I basically encode the text myself replacing line returns with HTML tags? and pass that on instead? Also is there another method you can suggest?

Comment: As I said in the answer, in HTML all white space characters (spaces, new lines, tab, et al) are treated as "a space".  That was one of the two suggestions I made in the answer. The other common method is CSS.

Comment: I appreciate your input but first the problem is related to URL encoding and not HTML. Second you suggest to change method where whether using get or post here is irrelevant. The problem here is with the content-type used for the AJAX request. So your suggestion is basically to encode the text myself but I am still interested to hear how other people do this.

Comment: @user18490 — That seems unlikely, the symptoms you describe point firmly at HTML. I have not suggested changing the method. You should URL Encode the text yourself instead of depending on the browser to error correct your URL, but that isn't the solution to your problem (which is to remember that HTML is not plain text and alter either the markup or the text accordingly).

Comment: @ Quentin your answer is not completely satisfactory for me, which is why I can't accept it, but it put me on the right track. So thx for that. Your answer contains some directions but it should get into more details to be useful to someone else. I will write a more complete answer later -- but your answers were useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding css `white-space:pre;` to target element , or replacing `\n` with `<br>` at `responseText`

```
var commentText = document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].innerText;
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST", "/echo/html/", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.onload = function() {
if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
  var text = xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.body.innerText = text;
};
};
xmlhttp.send("html=" + encodeURIComponent(commentText));
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aLesvqfk/1/